# How can I detect if a string ends with punctuation mark?

Tags: java

As the title said, how to do it in JAVA?

For example,

```
String example="Hello?";
```

The string contains `?` at the end, I need to detect it using JAVA.

Edit I need to detect all punctuation marks, not only `?`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to break your problem into two stages.  First, how can you detect one particular punctuation mark - such as a question mark? The answers below can guide you there.  Second, how can you apply this method multiple times for different marks in a programmatic way (not having to repeat yourself too much)? You may want to look up control flow structures such as loops to help you there.

Comment: As I said in the question, if the last character is punctuation mark, I need to return true, otherwise, false. I don't thing your answer can be used.

Comment: His answer can be used. 
Compare the end of the string to a vector of punctuation marks. If it's true then return it. 

He's suggesting that you create a method so you can reuse it and use a control flow to iterate through the vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex and its predefined `\p{Punct}` class which represents one of
`` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ `` characters. Just use

```
if (yourString.matches(".*\\p{Punct}");
```

Since `matches` checks if entire string can be matched with regex you need to let it also match characters before punctuation mark. To do so you can use `.*` where `.` represents any character (except line separators) and `*` means zero or more occurrences.

If you don't want to include all characters from `\p{Punct}` you can define your own [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) using for instance `[.?!]` to match only `.` `?` `!`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the last character of your string and use regular expression to validate it.